# How does .NET MVC know how to render a models attributes using lambda expressions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I’ve got a question about the default account model, view and controller generated when creating a new MVC 3 project in Visual Studio 2010 (using razor).
The generated AccountController uses this to load the view:

```
public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And the corresponding view (LogOn.cshtml) contains code like this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
```

My question is where is this variable “m” defined? How does it know that this refers to the model? There is no model being passed to the view but "m" still works. If I change all the references to “m” to another letter it still works! Could someone explain what’s going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a C# 3.0 feature called **"Lambda Expression"**.

You can check these nice articles to know what it is (by the way, it's amazingly useful).

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/10/03/lambda-expressions.aspx

http://blah.winsmarts.com/2006/05/19/demystifying-c-30--part-4-lambda-expressions.aspx

For the 2nd part of your question, if you notice, all the methods under `@Html` are model-related methods, which mean that all of them are expecting to work on your passed model.

And if you check the first line in your Logon view, you will find this line:

```
@model YOUR_APP_NAME.Models.LogOnModel
```

Which defines that the model type of this view is of type logonModel. (Which can be found inside your Models folder.)

This way, the weird `m` is represening the passed Logon model, and so we can access the properties under the passed model easily like typing `m.UserName`

Answer (score 1):

The 'm' in this situation if a variable name that is supplied as part of a [lamda expression](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx&rct=j&q=lambda%20expression%20c#&ei=d_SSTfG5JMSGhQfGoM2bDw&usg=AFQjCNGV-wHKd7l5lGFu-luKkhX1rKn6pw&sig2=SSWvM-0ldgGwP3LH4rVTeg&cad=rja).

From the link:

> All lambda expressions use the lambda
>   operator =>, which is read as "goes
>   to". The left side of the lambda
>   operator specifies the input
>   parameters (if any) and the right side
>   holds the expression or statement
>   block. The lambda expression x => x *
>   x is read "x goes to x times x."

Comment: ok but how does the view know that the result from the expression relates to the model?

Comment: @Matt27 Because your view will be compiled to a class that inherits from System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<T> where T is the type of your model class.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions are just shorthand C# delegates. Delegates are functions that can be passed as parameters, much like javascript functions, like callbacks.

`x => x.Name` is really just shorthand for creating one of these delegates, that takes some variable x as a parameter, and returns this variables Name property.

`(parameters) => (expression)`
Is shorthand for

```
Function(parameters) {
    return expression;
}
```

So `LabelFor` takes one of these shorthand functions as parameters, and runs it against the model context you have specified.